# Create Custom IBAction in Controller of my Custom View

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3

firstly I cannot post any Code but I´ll try to describe my problem as best as I can.

Ok. I created a Custom Swift View File as `view.xib` and loading it in my `view.swift` I loaded that `Xib`. The Xib is a simple `label` above a `imageview`.
I can create my `IBOutlet` in my `view.swift` file and e.g. switch the image or change the label. `view.swift` simply extends `UIView`.

So now I integrated this view in my `Storyboard` which has a Controller (lets call it `otherVC.swift`). Now `otherVC.swift` wants to get info that the `view.swift` is touched. I tried setting a `IBAction` but there no option to set on, just on `IBOutlet`. After some Googe I found that the Class `UiControl` has those mechanics to set a `IBAction`.

So I `view.swift` no longer extends `UIView` but now `UIControl`. After that I Could create an `IBAction` with a touch event. (like touch down or touch inside) When running the app with the view in the simulator I can click the view but the IBAction wont be callled.

So my question is how can I set a `IBAction` for my View in a other VC or maybe create my own `IBActions` for the specific view.

*again ..not able to post code. would welcome snippets or links with working example*

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your custom view?

Comment: yes but I want to send the Call that my view is being tapped to an other VC.

Comment: In that case you can use any observer like `Delegates` or `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: @Offset Are you showing the image completely filling the view.swift?

Comment: @AravindAR no . its a squre imageview and ontop is a labelview. both in the same layer. I just understand why there isnt a custom IBAction pattern which I implement and drag from my view to the controller :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it will be hard to create a custom `IBAction` (if not impossible), but your problem has many other solutions like delegates, notifications, or closures. I recommend that you use closures as it is the simplest way in my opinion.

Below is example code of how you could achieve this with closures:

```
class View: UIView {

    var someButtonTapped: (UIButton) -> Void = { _ in }

    @IBAction private func someButtonTappedAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        someButtonTapped(sender)
    }
}
```

Then in your controller, add this:

```
objectOfYourCustomView.someButtonTapped = { (sender: UIButton) in
    // Handle action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understood i am answering on that basis. 
Create the public property of your views u want to access in the viewcontroller.
You will be able to access customview. propertyName.
Hope this may help.