# How to make @IBAction from a custom view in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xib, ibaction, custom-view

I added a custom view, that has a button, to my `viewController`. I want to make an `@IBAction` from that button to my `viewController`.
I have following problems:

1. How do I make it show up in a storyboard? When I run the app it works fine.
2. How do I make an `@IBAction` from that button to my `viewController`?

```swift
    class CustomCellView: UIView{    
      //MARK: Initializer

      override func awakeFromNib() {
          super.awakeFromNib()
      }

      override init(frame: CGRect) {
          super.init(frame: frame)
          commonInit()
      }
      required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: coder)
          commonInit()
      }

      override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
          super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
          commonInit()
      }

     //MARK: Functions

      func commonInit(){
          let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("customCellView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView ?? UIView()
          customView.frame = self.bounds
          self.addSubview(customView)
      }
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to make this view IBDesignable?

Comment: You probably don't need to create an `@IBAction`. Just make an optional closure and provide it from `viewController`, and call the closure from the `@IBAction` 'within' your `CustomCellView` class.

Comment: I made it to IBDesignable but same result

Comment: I need @IBAction in viewController to process some data.

Comment: I founded my answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845562/create-custom-ibaction-in-controller-of-my-custom-view

Answer (score 0):

Add `@objc` in your `viewController` where you added `customView`.

- e.g.

```
    @objc func actionCustom()
    {
        print("Click Added") 
    }
```

- Use

```
func commonInit(){
      let customView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("customCellView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView ?? UIView()
      customView.frame = self.bounds
      self.addSubview(customView)

      customView.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionCustom), for: .touchUpInside) //Add click code here
  }
```

Comment: actionCustom in commonInit() gives error: "Use of unresolved identifier 'actionCustom'"

Answer (score -2):

1. my customView is not showing in storyboard but when I run the app it's ok

   This is the expected behaviour with the custom views. You won't get to see how the view looks in the xib that you use the custom view only in the xib that you defined the view.
2. How make @IBAction from that button to my viewController.

   You can't. Custom views don't make public the subviews in interface builder. The best thing you can do is to use the delegate pattern or as Bhavesh Sarsawa pointed out doing it programatically either by adding the vc as a target or by making an IBAction in the ccustom view which calls a closure that is sent by dependency injection.

```
customButton.setAction { code that gets called when the button is pressed }
```