# "'_' can only appear in a pattern or on the left side of an assignment"-Error when creating closure

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, closures, ibaction

I'm creating a closure to call from a storyboard outside the framework I'm creating.
However, when trying to implement said closure through the guidance of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44846816/12232029) SO post, I'm getting the following errors:

```
1. '_' can only appear in a pattern or on the left side of an assignment
2. Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
3. Expected expression
```

Here is the current code inside my swift file:

```
//Here is where I'm getting the mentioned 3 errors
var sliderChangeforward: (UISlider) -> Void { _ in }

@IBAction func sliderDidChange(_ sender: UISlider){
    
    ...

    sliderChangeforward(sender)
    
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You omitted the equals sign.

```
var sliderChangeforward: (UISlider) -> Void = { _ in }
```